# Creating Tasks - System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, limitexception

To complete this challenge, you need to add a trigger for Opportunity. The trigger will add a task to any opportunity inserted or updated with the stage of 'Closed Won'. The task's subject must be 'Follow Up Test Task'.
The Apex trigger must be called 'ClosedOpportunityTrigger'
With 'ClosedOpportunityTrigger' active, if an opportunity is inserted or updated with a stage of 'Closed Won', it will have a task created with the subject 'Follow Up Test Task'.
To associate the task with the opportunity, fill the 'WhatId' field with the opportunity ID.
This challenge specifically tests 200 records in one operation.

Ans:

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    List<Task> myTasklist       =    new List<Task>();
        for(Opportunity myOpp : trigger.new){
        if(myOpp.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
            Task myTask = new Task();
            myTask.Subject      =    'Follow Up Test Task';
            myTask.WhatId       =    myOpp.ID;
            myTasklist.add(myTask);           
        }   
    }
    insert myTasklist;
}
```

Error:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong: 
>   There was an unexpected error in your org which is preventing this assessment check from completing: System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151

Comment: Code looks ok. Do you have a non-bulkified trigger on the task object?

Comment: I guess no,so how to write non bulkified trigger on task?

Comment: Confused by your comment, you want to know how to write a non-bulkified trigger?

Comment: yes I would like to know how to create non-bulkified trigger on task.

Comment: Sorry, it goes against everything in me to knowingly teach someone how to do something the wrong way. You do realize that the non-bulkified comment was because that sort of trigger/code would cause the error not make it go away

Comment: Did you check that you don't have any other Opportunity triggers running DML statements in your org? Only with that trigger inside an org, it's impossible to get that error.

Comment: Yeah almost certain you have more than one trigger on `Opportunity`, because the code in your example won't hit the limit. I think that's what @Eric was getting at in the first place.

Comment: @Eric I guess he is not communicating properly. He wants to know how a non bulked trigger looks like so that he can spot one and make it right :)

Comment: @SfdcBat - Or I am not listening properly :) - A non-bulkified trigger is one that has DML (Insert/update/delete) inside of a loop (typically a For loop). Look at your other trigger on Opportunity/Task for this as the OP code is bulkified

Comment: Thank you guys... I just found in other trigger I wrote DML statement inside a FOR loop...

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that you have other triggers on `Opportunity`, and that one of them is *not* properly bulkified. This is one of the many reasons **One Trigger Per Object** is listed first in **[Trigger Frameworks and Apex Trigger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)**. I highly recommend adopting a handler pattern and beginning to work on **One Trigger Per Ojbect**, even as you work through Trailhead modules.

Comment: @manideep - or possibly, triggers on Task that do non-bulkified DML

Answer (score -1):

```
trigger ClosedOpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
    for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id,Name FROM Opportunity WHERE StageName='Closed Won']){
       Task t = new Task();
        t.Subject ='Follow Up Test Task';
        t.WhatId = opp.Id;
       TaskList.add(t);
    }
    insert TaskList;
}
```

//Try this